# OS X Messages.app images are out of sync with Contacts

Tags: macos, contacts, messages

I synchronize my contacts on OS X under Internet Accounts. I have contacts selected under iCloud, Google, Facebook and LinkedIn.

I've updated contact images using this profile aggregation and it shows up in Contacts.app. The trouble is they won't synchronize with Messages.app.

Is there a way to force a synchronization? Can it be done without deletion of messages?

I really don't wish to delete my past conversations if possible.

Comment: Anybody? Curious to get some feedback here...

Comment: For those still curious as I am, I've found a lot doesn't work. Removal to any of the `plist` values in `~/Library/Preferences` and `/Library/Preferences` related to iChat, Messages and AddressBook does nothing for images. There must be some sort of loading process I cannot track down just yet.